# Which Data structure should I use for Data mining algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to implement two Interaction pattern algorithms (IPM and IPM2) , I'm currently halfway through my first algorithm. Unfortunately,I am new in data mining and I don't know appropriate data structures to use them in my algorithms.

First algorithm is to find frequent patterns from large datasets, the datasets are from (SPMF) website. first I need to use a data structure that is scalable or it must handle larger datasets every time. and another problem is that I have to create a matrix A*A, (A = size of the dataset) then the challenge is to put patterns of length 2 in an index matrix[j][j]. is it possible to put more than one pair into one index? for example (3,2) is a pattern and I want to store it in (matrix[2][2]) and if the pattern is (4,29) I want to store it into the index [29][29]. what is the best data structure to do that? I tried ArrayList and List and now I am creating a matrix but it's not appropriate. any help is appreciated if you can understand the question.

Comment: Perhaps if you show us some code and try to explain what is wrong with it.  It is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I knew it will be unclear but I really don't know how to explain it because it's too complex. actually I will try to explain better than that.

Comment: "I really don't know how to explain it because it's too complex" That is often (but not always!) a sign that you haven't actually broken down the problem enough. If you break it down to a number of smaller problems, each of which is _not_ too complex, then it could be you'll have answered your own question!

Comment: Data mining is a big topic.  You need to spend several days, if not weeks, researching algorithms and data structures.  It's not going to be a 30 line answer.